Performing Correspondence Analysis in r
I am experimenting Correspondence Analysis with R in the Airline Passenger Satisfaction dataset and I encountered this error

The value of the argument axes is incorrect. ",  (tp.R#82): argument is of length zero

This is the code
data <- read.csv("dataset3.csv")

columns_to_include <- c("Type.of.Travel", "Class", "Seat.Comfort", "Cleanliness", "Food.and.Drink", "In.flight.Service", "In.flight.Entertainment", "Baggage.Handling","Satisfaction")

# Subset the data to include only the specified columns
data <- data[1:100, columns_to_include]

cont_table <- table(data$Class, data$Baggage.Handling)
print("Contingency Table - Class vs Satisfaction:")
print(cont_table)

# Perform CA on contingency table
ca_result <- CA(cont_table)


# Visualize CA results
p6 <- fviz_ca_biplot(ca_result,
                     repel = TRUE,
                     title = "CA Biplot - Class vs Satisfaction")
print(p6)

I don't know why I get this error and I tried changing the variables but no luck

CA is not a base R function. When using functions that are not base R functions please start the scripts with a call to library(pkgname) in order to load the packages needed. Does that function come from package FactoMineR?

Yes I am importing that from FactominR

With the Kaggle data set in the link (my edit), I am not able to reproduce the error, everything works after correcting some upper case words in the column names you posted. Is that the data set you are using?

Thank you for the edit , i already fixed the problem, there was some changes (mainly changing the columns and the data so it is no more numerical but categories (Satisfied , non Satisfied and Neutral) made to the dataset by my colleague that caused that , i should've clearly posted the dataset i am using,, that's my bad
